# Show that a function on invertible operators is continuous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, proof-writing, operator-theory

If $L(\mathbb{R^n})^{−1}$ is the set of all invertible operators in $L(\mathbb{R^n})$, and if T ∈ $L(\mathbb{R^n})$ such that ||T || < 1

I've already proved that

(a) the series  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} T^k $ converges,

(b) $I_n − T$  $\in L(\mathbb{R^n})$, and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}T^k = \frac{1}{I_n −T}$

Let the function $F$ : $L(\mathbb{R^n})^{-1}$ → $L(\mathbb{R^n})^{-1}$ be defined by $T$  → $T^{−1}$

Now I would like to show the following:

(i) The function F is continuous at $I_n$.

(ii) The function F is continuous on $L(\mathbb{R^n})^{-1}$

Comment: Did you mean $T^k$ instead of $T_k$?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I've corrected it now.

Comment: ii) is wrongly stated. $F$ is not defined on the whole of $L(\mathbb R^{n})$

Comment: Thanks, You're right it should have been $L(\mathbb{R^n})^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the series expansion you have obtained $||(I_n-T)^{-1}-I_n|| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty } ||T^{k}|| =\frac {||T||} {1-||T||} $. Hence $||F(I_n-T)-F(I_n)|| \leq \frac {||T||} {1-||T||} $. Letting $||T|| \to 0$ we see that $F$ is continuous at $I_n$. If $T_k \to T \in L(\mathbb R^{n})^{-1}$ then $T^{-1}T_n \to I_n$ so $F(T^{-1}T_n) \to I_n$. Can you deduce from this that $F(T_n) \to F(T)$?

Comment: I'm having trouble to see that $F(T_n) -> F(T) $...

Comment: $(T^{-1}T_n)^{-1} \to I_n$ or $T_n^{-1}T \to I_n$. Therefore $T_n^{-1} =T_n^{-1}T T^{-1} \to I_nT^{-1}=T^{-1}$.